# Directive not being applied

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following directives aren't being applied in my html.  I tried copying an example from the documentation, and it works up until I change the name to match my element.  What's going on?  Using angular 1.2.26 (legacy project that I haven't been able to upgrade yet)

Directives:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="data-breakdown.html">
    <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-vcenter" ng-transclude></table>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="data-breakdown-field.html">
    <tr>
        <th ng-bind="label"></th>
        <td ng-bind="value"></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script>
    app.directive('dataBreakdown', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'data-breakdown.html',
            transclude: true,
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                angular.element(elem).addClass('table-responsive');
            }
        }
    }]);
    app.directive('dataBreakdownField', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'data-breakdown-field.html',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                label: '&',
                field: '&'
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<data-breakdown>
  <data-breakdown-field label="Name" value="John Smith"></data-breakdown-field>
  <data-breakdown-field label="Age" value="42"></data-breakdown-field>
</data-breakdown>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the name of the directive.

Angular removes the data- prefix from elements as well as attributes.

To fix, just remove the data prefix on the name and it will work as expected.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/guide/directive#matching-directives